# How to read Firebase saved data when there is no change in data? || How can I read saved data when there is no change in database?

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing a strange issue. While reading from Firebase android app crashes and gives me a nullpointerexception. I assure you that there is data in realtime database and there is no mistake in id either.

Currently this app is devided into two parts.

1. When I click on "pumpst" it saves data into realtime database.
2. When I click on "sysst" it reads data from realtime database.

**Scenario:**
When I open the app and click on sysst it crashes and gives me an exception. But, when I click pumpst first and then sysst then it gives me the data.

**Problem:**
It is possible that when i open the app the first thing i want is data. But, snapshot is going to retrieve data only when there is a data change because of onDataChange() method. But, What if i want to read the stored data?

**Expected working**
When application opens and I click on sysst it should show me data saved in realtime database.

**THINGS I TRIED**
I tried putting try and cache for reading data just to prevent crash. But, now it is crashing because of valueEventListner.
I have tried youtube as well as google. But, couldn't find the actual solution.

Here is my android code.

```
package com.example.ingene;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView pumpst,sysst;
DatabaseReference myRef;
String str;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
    init();

    pumpst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

            myRef.child("member").setValue("Mem").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() 
{
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Toast.makeText(HomePage.this," Data Saved Successfully 
:",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(HomePage.this,"Cannot Insert Data...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    sysst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    try {
                        str = snapshot.child("member").getValue().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(HomePage.this,str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(HomePage.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

        }
    });
}


void init()
{
    pumpst = findViewById(R.id.pump_status_txtv);
    sysst = findViewById(R.id.system_status_txtv);
    
}
}
```

Here is the Exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ingene, PID: 14234
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.ingene.HomePage$2.onClick(HomePage.java:67)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7256)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7218)
    at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:824)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27719)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:228)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7782)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:981)
```

Here is the screenshot of database

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fmb9cFYUg_JpDYCNmDjX-LhxTMRAzIOH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What do you mean by "But, now it is crashing because of valueEventListner."?

Comment: @AlexMamo When I didn't wrote try and cache the exception message was pointing me on line 71 which is "snapshot.getvalue().toString()"  but, now I have added try and cache and it is poointing at line 67 which is "@override" but that is not the problem. and as per the exception message it encountered exception on "com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)" this method. So, now it is crashing because this valueEventListner.

Comment: Your `myRef` has not been initialised yet prior `sysst` call, so try setting `myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();` below the `init();` line.